# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an eCommerce Site in React.js and I am having "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined" in Chrome. Here is also a screenshot of the error and VS Code same as the Code itself where the error is taking place.
Please help! I would be very grateful!  :)

Here you can see the code and the Error

[image: Here you can see the code and the Error]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products'


const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id)

  return (
    <>
        <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
            Go Back
        </Link>
        <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <Rating value={product.rating} text ={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} />
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </>
    )    
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: Is `react-router-bootstrap` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
```

to

```
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

then error is gone.

with **react-router-bootstrap** you can change:

```
<Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
  Go Back
</Link>
```

to

```js
<LinkContainer to="/">
  <Button>Go Back</Button>
</LinkContainer>
```

LinkContainer is imported from react-router-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

According to the `react-router-bootstrap` document:

> It's an integration between React Router v4 and React Bootstrap by wrapping your React Bootstrap element in a `<LinkContainer>`.

So just import `<LinkContainer>` from `react-router-bootstrap`, for another component like `List` and `Button` import them from `react-bootstrap` package, so install it according to it's [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#installation)

*Personally I see no reason to use `react-router-bootstrap` package.*